# jQuery horizontal scrolling of text on mouseover

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I would really appreciate some help based on the following image:

[image]

Furthermore, I am trying to accomplish (infinite) scrolling of the green text within `div.title-holder`. My aim is for the scrolling to begin only on *mouseOver* and then reset on *mouseOut* of `div.container`. I thought this would have been a simple task with a bit of CSS and jQuery, but apparently not so. Here is my HTML, CSS and accompanying JS:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="title-holder">
        <a href="somelink.html">long text that needs to scroll</a>
    </div>
    <img src="someimage.jpg" />
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
div.title-holder {
  width:130px;
  height:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:no-wrap;
  text-align:center;
}
div.title-holder a {      
}
```

jQuery JS:

```
$('div.container').hover(
    function () {
        var scrollingWidth = $(this).find('div.title-holder').find('a').width();
        $(this).find('div.title-holder').stop(true, true).animate({scrollLeft: scrollingWidth}, { duration: 5000, easing: 'swing' });
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find('div.title-holder').stop(true, true).animate({scrollLeft: 0}, { duration: 5000, easing: 'swing' });
    }
);
```

Now, this works okay, except for 2 problems:

1. It does not scroll infinitely, and
2. The scroll action is **very very** jumpy/jittery

I really do hope that someone has had a similar requirement in the past and can shed some light on this matter for me.  **Thank you!**

Comment: I know that this has been asked before, but my desired end-result is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer using setInterval. Maybe this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raymondralibi/KpuyT/1/) will help.

Comment: Hi Raymond, and thanks for the fiddle - it works exactly as I desired it to! One thing though, the scroll actions tends to be a tad bit jittery...any ideas of how this jitter can be minimized?  I've also updated the fiddkle to scroll only if the hyperlink width is longer than its parent-container's width (http://jsfiddle.net/KpuyT/3/)

Comment: really sorry, i don't know exactly how to minimize the jitter. maybe using native javascript instead of jquery (for some function) will working.

Comment: It's cool, I'll play around with the interval milliseconds. If only there was a way to integrate jquery's easing into setInterval.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this!  Scrolling text and doling information out like that is a [huge](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/990502.html), [usability](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/web-accessibility/web-accessibility-usability.shtml) [problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element#Usability_problems).
[image: Scrolling text is bad!!!]

Use that and you will annoy 80% of the page's <strike>victims</strike> users, and most will not read/see, or will ignore, the title as well.

Write titles with [the First 2 Words](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/nanocontent.html) in mind, and display them like this if they absolutely must be too long. :

[image: A better pattern]

... where the "more" link pops up a div with the full title.

Comment: Brock, I could not agree with you any more. Unfortunately, he who pays the pier calls the tune! This was discussed with the client, but this is how they wanted it done. This is actually for a photo gallery (CMS powered by Drupal), so I need to cater for the content editor entering a really long title. Each `div.container` is nested as follows `ul > li > div.container`, so on one page, there are at least 9 of these. If you have any other sugesstions, please don't hesitate to offer any advice. Thanks!

Comment: sorry: "...he who pays the **piper**..."

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sMmkX/10/)**

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi Shankar, thank you for the fiddle. Unfortunately, the extra text gets chopped off

Comment: @Shalan - What extra text? You can play up with the fiddle to meet up your expectations. I gave a good start to you.

Comment: `<a>long text that needs to scroll</a>` gets truncated to `<a>long text that needs</a>`.  The extra text is ` to scroll` that is the overflowed text that needs to come into view when scrolling. Currently only the truncated text scrolls. Have a look at the fiddle again.

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with your CSS! It's veery simple to make it work. Just adding one line of CSS:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

Here it is, the complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/sMmkX/115/